# Community Promotion Ads — 2020

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2020 has come! But… oops, where did the time go? It’s already March! Belated as it is, it’s time for a refresh of **Community Promotion Ads**!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/8492).

Answer (score 22):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: Copied from 2019.

Comment: I read somewhere it runs a cryptocurrency miner in the browser.

Comment: @hola could you explain a bit more? I just checked the web site and afais there is no cryptomining stuff loaded. They try to load stuff from gittip/gratipay which ceased in 2017, but nothing related to mining. Do you have any references to your statement or supporting data?

Comment: @norbert I read it from here. http://tug.org/mail-archives/texhax/2011-June/017593.html

Comment: @norbert Probably they stopped it. The mailing list is quite old.

Answer (score 21):

[image: LaTeX]

Comment: Copied from 2019.

Answer (score 20):

[image: TeX Live - cross-platform TeX software]

Comment: Copied from 2019.

Comment: Barbara, we should change the font of that here to cmss as we have dinner for all other logos etc.

Answer (score 19):

[image: TeX Users Group]

Comment: Copied from 2019.

Answer (score 19):

[image: The TeX User Group]

Comment: Copied from 2019.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 16):

[image: TeX online documentation lookup system]

Comment: A service for TeX users who don't have the documentation installed, for easy lookup, for example for Overleaf users.

Answer (score 14):

[image: TEXample.net]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Step by step TikZ tutorials]

Comment: It seems that the link is dead.

Answer (score 13):

[image: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/]

Comment: Copied from 2019.

Answer (score 12):

[image: ConTeXt Garden]

Answer (score 9):

[image: DANTE e.V. - German language TeX users group]

Answer (score 8):

[image: TeX talk - news and interviews]

Comment: Blog that hosts the [Interviews](http://tex-talk.net/category/tex-sx/interviews/) of TeX.SE users.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Publication quality figure labels with LaTeX and Mathematica]

Answer (score 7):

[image: LaTeX Community Forum - Talk about TeX and LaTeX]

Answer (score 6):

[image: TeX questions and answers in French]

Comment: A growing community of French TeX friends thanks to the effort of Denis and Patrick and others.

Answer (score 6):

[image: TeXwelt - Fragen und Antworten zu TeX auf Deutsch]

Comment: This site and other sites are supported by [DANTE e.V.](http://www.dante.de).

Answer (score 4):

[image: Mathpix Snip | Equation to LaTeX]

Comment: Mathpix, an OCR tool for TeX equations. Very useful and has good free plans.

Comment: Good, but still has some recognizing problem!

Comment: Used it, its cool.